# increasing pattern density with grid.pattern

Tags: r, graphics

The `grid.pattern` function supplied by `gridExtra` will fill a polygon with diagonal lines.  I want to increase the density of lines, i.e., the number of diagonal lines that appears in any given space.  Is there an argument that I can pass to `grid.pattern` that controls the density of lines?

Here's a minimal example:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.pattern(pattern = 1)
```

That code draws a rectangle covered by diagonal lines.  How can I change the code so that the rectangle includes (say) twice as many lines?  I've read the function documentation and tried changing some arguments to `grid.pattern`, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `granularity` argument to set the distance between the diagonal lines:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.pattern(pattern = 1, granularity = unit(2.5, "mm")) ## (Default is 5 mm)
```

Comment: +1 funny, i could have sworn this `granularity` argument wasn't controlling anything! (as the doc would have us believe, too)

Comment: @baptiste -- That's especially funny since you wrote the function, didn't you? I also read the docs first, but dug a little deeper, hoping there must be some way to pass in a value via `patternGrob`, and turned out there was.

Comment: i did, indeed :) This is really a proof-of-concept function, not one I expect to be used by others (my conclusion was that this should really be implemented at a lower level)