# aligning patterns across panels with gridExtra and grid.pattern()

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

The `gridExtra` package adds a grob of class "pattern" that lets one fill rectangles with patterns.  For example,

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.pattern(pattern = 1)
```

creates a box filled with diagonal lines.  I want to create a stack of panels in which each panel is filled with these diagonal lines.  This is easy:

```
library(lattice); library(gridExtra)
examplePlot <- xyplot(
  1 ~ 1 | 1:2, 
  panel = function () grid.pattern(pattern = 1),
  layout = c(1, 2),

  # Remove distracting visual detail
  scales = list(x=list(draw=FALSE), y=list(draw=FALSE)),
  strip = FALSE, xlab = '', ylab = ''
)
print(examplePlot)
```

The problem is that the diagonal lines aren't aligned across panels.  That is, there is a visual "break" where the bottom of the first panel meets the top of the second panel: at that point, the lines don't line up.  This is the problem that I want to fix.

I can eliminate most of the visual break by adding the argument `pattern.offset = c(.2005, 0)` to the `grid.pattern` call, and making sure that it applies only to the bottom panel.  But this solution doesn't generalize.  For example, if I change the pattern (e.g., by using the `granularity` argument to `grid.pattern`), this solution won't work.  Is there a more general fix?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy answer to this without changing yourself the (highly experimental) implementation of `patternGrob`. Could you describe the more general context of your question -- what are you trying to do? It may be that there is an easier way to do it without using this unreliable function.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  Really, all I am trying to do is fill panels with patterns and ensure that the patterns line up seamlessly across panels.  For an example, see the figure in the response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, you'll have to take charge of setting the `panel.height` argument used by `print.trellis`.  (To see why, try resizing your plotting device after running your example code: as the size of the device and the panels changes, so does the matching/mismatching of the lines):

```
## Calculate vertical distance (in mm) between 45 degree diagonal lines
## spaced 5mm apart (the default distance for grid.pattern).
vdist <- 5 * sqrt(2)

nLines <- 8L    ## can be any integer
panelHeight <- list(x = nLines*vdist, units = "mm", data = NULL)

## Plot it
print(examplePlot, panel.height=panelHeight)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- this solution works. But it seems to imply that panels must be at least 5 * sqrt(2) = 7.071mm high if the 45-degree diagonal lines are to be aligned across panels. Is that correct?

Comment: @user697473 -- That's correct, if you use the default inter-line width (or 'granularity') of 5mm. If you changed the granularity (as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987974/increasing-pattern-density-with-grid-pattern/10988301#10988301)), and the panel height in concert, you could get panels of different heights.